# How to set a function key(f2) for rename a tab

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the attached screen shot you can she that to rename a selected tab we have to click on it, and to delete a tab  we need a mouse hover on the unselected tab. Now this events are not key board accessible. For this I want to set the f2 key for rename, ie. when a tab is selected I can rename it by pressing the f2 key and to delete the tab I want to fix the delete button on the tab instead of a mouse hover and can make it key board accessible.

Now I need the solution for both of this two problem and I can provide the css code for deleting the tab.

```
.js .delete-tab {
    background: url(../images/common/remove.png) no-repeat 42%;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 2px;
    text-indent: -9999em;
    top: 2px;
    width: 8px;
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You can add a `keydown` event to the body, so that you get notified of which key is pressed in your document. Use `e.keyCode` to know which key - F2 has keyCode 113.

Comment: From a usability perspective please keep in mind that F2 to rename is a Windows function. Might not be as intuitive for Linux/Mac users. So be sure to communicate it clearly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jQuery way:

```
$('body').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 113) {
        // F2 was pressed
        // e.target holds a reference to the current DOM element
    }
});
```

Comment: @ Matty can i do this by css or is there any other way ?